# NullPointerException when trying to draw a graph using Android Drawing

Tags: android, drawing, nullpointerexception

I want to sketch a graph that track the user weight progress,
I am writing a method that I can call in the onCreat event,
 this is my code:

```
 public void drawGraph(){
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();   
private int width = display.getWidth();  
private int height = display.getHeight();                                               
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Canvas canvas =new Canvas();
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, height, paint); // the x-axes represent the date        
    canvas.drawLine(0, height, width, height, paint); // the y-axes represent the weight  

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawLine(0, max, width, max, paint); //draw the maximum healthy weight
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawLine(0, min, width, min, paint); // draw the minimum healthy weight
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawLine(0, gW, width, gW, paint); // draw the goal weight
            int xDis = width/weekNumbers;
            int y;
    Path path = new Path();     
    for (int i = 0; i <= Weightvalues; i++){
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT CURRENTWEIGHT FROM WEIGHT WHERE DATECREATED > " + startDate, null);
        int weight;
        if (c!=null){
            if (c.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    weight = c.getInt(0);
                    // I want now to find out for each entry the point represent it on the graph
                    y = Math.round(weight * y / range); //range is the difference between the maximum weight and the minimum weight
                    if (i==1)
                        path.moveTo(0, y);
                    else
                        path.lineTo(0 + i*xDis, height-y);

                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    }
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

}
```

this is the onCreat event

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.weight_chart);
      helper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
      drawGraph();
}
```

when i run the program i faced this error

```
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(738): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{*********.WeightChart}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can any body review it for me and tell me where i went wrong

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to use Canvas without assigning it a Bitmap to do drawing onto. To get your image on screen, one way is to define ImageView in your layout xml;

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/graph_image" />
```

Accompanied with following changes to your drawGraph method;

```
...
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapCreateBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
...
Do your drawing stuff..
...
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.graph_image);
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: excuse me, these three lines were outside the method, but I add them in the question for more clarity, I fix these errors, now there is no error but also no graph, it is empty

Comment: is this because the layout I set it to it?

Comment: @Heba: Ok, I will edit end part away. Anyway, getWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay() is something I've seen being used widely. Are you sure it's the line causing the NullPointerException?

Comment: no error now is occurred , it just there is nothing on screen

Comment: @Heba: It's a good start if we got over the NullPointerException. What you're doing now, if you added the Bitmap assigning to Canvas already, is drawing into off-screen bitmap, but never drawing it on screen. You might want to take a look on [View.onDraw(Canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) next but this discussion goes beyond this question.

Comment: @Heba: Actually, thinking of it, maybe there's easier way to have your bitmap on screen. Will modify my answer accordingly.